# ng-click is not working in ui-bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, uipopover

```
     <div ng-repeat = "offer in productOffers">
       <div class = "col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-left mrg-5 selr-name"
         uib-popover-html = 
          "'<img src=assets/images/cart-blue.png 
            class=img-cart 
            ng-click=addProductToCart(offer,finalProduct)/> 

            <div class=fonts-13  
            ng-click=addProductToCart(offer,finalProduct)> 
            Add To Cart
           </div>'">
       </div>
   </div>
```

Here, I have added my code, I want to **use ng-click inside popover** element and I have ng-repeat for popover, so neeed to add popover HTML inline. **ng-click is not working inside popover**.

Plunker [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/v4fk1PzxY51TL7K2ObEe?p=preview)

Thanks in advance. Any help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks at first glance like a scoping issue because the popover creates a new child scope, so it would never work anyway.

Comment: @VijayKrishna I have added plunker link in my question, kindly go through it. here it's not scope issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use **uib-popover-template** insted of **uib-popover-html**.
working plucker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XX6hvHCJgThQ82NANPsX?p=preview)

```
<div ng-repeat = "offer in productOffers">
  <div class = "col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-left mrg-5 selr-name"
     uib-popover-template= 
      "'tpl.html'">
</div> 
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
   <img src="assets/images/cart-blue.png" 
        class="img-cart" 
        ng-click="addProductToCart(offer,finalProduct)"/> 

        <div class="fonts-13"  
        ng-click="addProductToCart(offer,finalProduct)"> 
        Add To Cart
       </div>
</script>
```